# Prove that the order of the centralizer $C(κ) ⊂ S_n$ is $6(n − 5)!$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $κ = (123)(45) ∈ S_n$, where n ≥ 5. Prove that the order of the centralizer $C(κ) ⊂ S_n$ is $6(n − 5)!$ I think I am meant to use the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem here but I am not sure how to apply it.

Comment: If you want to do it that way you should let $S_n$ act on itself by conjugation and see how many elements are in the same orbit as ...

Comment: @ancientmathematician: I think that is the intended answer. If the OP doesn't catch on in due time, I would like to encourage you to flesh it out to an answer. No pressure. Your call, of course :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I am still hoping the OP will offer us this solution. It's a good example on the O-S Thm because we can do the count both ways and see that it is really true!

Answer (score 1):

If $\pi$ commutes with $\kappa$ then for all $x$ occurring in a $k$-cycle of $\kappa$, $\pi(x)$ also occurs in a $k$-cycle of $\kappa$.
Consequently, $\pi$ is some permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$, together with some permutation of $\{4,5\}$, together with some permutation of $\{6,\ldots,n\}$.
We readily verify that we can take an arbitrary permutation of $\{6,\ldots,n\}$ (i.e., the centralizer of the identity in $S_{n-5}$ is all of $S_{n-5}$), and an arbitrary permutation of $\{4,5\}$ (i.e., the centralizer of the non-trivial element of $S_2$ is all of $S_2$), but only an even permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$ (i.e., the centralizer of $(1\,2\,3)\in S_3$ is $A_3$). We conclude that $C(\kappa)$ is isomorphic to $A_3\times S_2\times S_{n-5}$.